# From step functions to continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This is problem 27 from Chapter 13 of Spivak's *Calculus*. The idea is the following. We have proved in a previous exercise that, if $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$, then, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there are step functions $s_1, s_2$ defined on the same interval and such that $s_1 \leq f \leq s_2$ and $\int^b_a f - \int^b_a s_1 < \varepsilon$ and $\int^b_a s_2 - \int^b_a f < \varepsilon$. Problem 27 then asks us to prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there are *continuous* functions with the same property.

So the problem reduces to one of obtaining a continuous function from a given step functions in such a way to preserve the desired property. I have been thinking of something along the following lines. Suppose the hypothesis and let $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary, and let $s_1$ be a step function such that $\int^b_a f - \int^b-a s_1 < \varepsilon$. Let $P=\{t_0, \dots, t_n\}$ be the coarsest partition such that $s_1$ is a step function on $P$. For each interval $[t_i, t_{i+1}]$, my idea was to find $\delta_i$ such that $[t_{i+1} - \delta_i, t_{i+1}]$ is a proper subset of $[t_i, t_{i+1}]$ and then defining $g_i$ such that $g_i(t_{i+1} - \delta_i) = s_1(t_{i+1} - \delta_i)$, $g_i(t_{i+1})=s_1(t_{i+1})$ and $g_i$ is a linear function.

It's not entirely clear to me, however, if this is enough (how do I show that this preserves the desired property?), and, if it is, how to find $\delta_i$---can I take any $\delta_i$, as long as $[t_{i+1} - \delta_i, t_{i+1}]$ is a proper subset of $[t_i, t_{i+1}]$? Or are there other conditions?

Finally, this method seems a little crude, to me... is there a better setting for solving this problem? I don't know, I just have the impression that there should be a more streamlined technique of obtaining continuous functions from step functions while preserving certain properties...

Comment: The function f(x) = tanh(x/c) is an example of a continuous version of the step function. By choosing the parameter $c$ (the width of the transition region) sufficiently small, the function will satisfy the properties as required by Spivak.